# Am trying to filter through comment object of Post, but I keep getting all the comments, How do i get each separate comment to it user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Here is my post listview that i want the comment of each user to be assign to their post, but i am having a challenge figuring out how to get each users comment instead i get all the comments in one users post?

```
def post_listview(request,*args,**kwargs):
    context =  {}
    cart = Cart(request)
    user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
    user = request.user
    post_comment = Comment.objects.filter()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.post = post
            data.username = user
            data.save()
            return redirect('feed', pk=user_id)
    else:
        form = NewCommentForm()
    for user in Post.objects.all():
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user=request.user )
                friends = friend_list.friends.all()

                context['friends'] = friends
    

    context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
    context['cart'] = cart
    context['post_comment'] = post_comment
    

    return render(request,'feed/feed.html',context)
```

Here is my url for the post list view!

```
path('', views.post_listview, name="feed"),
```

This is the template tag that i user in my template to render the comments

```
{% for comment in post_comment %}

{{ comment.body }}

{% endfor %} But it shows all the comment in one post, 
which is not the desire result i want, how best do i got about this ?
```

My post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/post/img' ,blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="users") 
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    

    @property
    def pic_url(self):
        if self.pic and hasattr(self.pic, 'url'):
            return self.pic.url

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('feed', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def get_date_posted(self):
        time = datetime.now()
        if self.date_posted.day == time.day:
            return str(time.hour - self.date_posted.hour) + " hrs"
        else:
            if self.date_posted.month == time.month:
                return str(time.day - self.date_posted.day) + "d"
            else:
                if self.date_posted.year == time.year:
                    return str(time.month - self.date_posted.month) + " months ago"
        return self.date_posted
 

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This is my template that i want the comments to be.

```
  {% for post in posts %}
              <div class="card lg:mx-0 uk-animation-slide-bottom-small">
      
                  <!-- post header-->
                  <div class="flex justify-between items-center lg:p-4 p-2.5">
                      <div class="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-4">
                          <a href="#">
                              <img src="{{post.user_name.profile_pic.url}}" class="bg-gray-200 border border-white rounded-full w-10 h-10">
                          </a>
                          <div class="flex-1 font-semibold capitalize">
                              <a href="#" class="text-black dark:text-gray-100"> {{ post.user_name.get_full_name }} </a>
                              <div class="text-gray-700 flex items-center space-x-2">  <span> {{ post.date_posted|timesince }}  </span> <ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    <div>
                      <a href="{% url 'feed:post-detail' post.id %}"> <i class="icon-feather-more-horizontal text-2xl hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-full p-2 transition -mr-1 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"></i> </a>
                      <div class="bg-white w-56 shadow-md mx-auto p-2 mt-12 rounded-md text-gray-500 hidden text-base border border-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 dark:border-gray-700" 
                      uk-drop="mode: click;pos: bottom-right;animation: uk-animation-slide-bottom-small">
                    
                          <ul class="space-y-1">
                            <li> 
                                <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-gray-800">
                                 <i class="uil-share-alt mr-1"></i> Share
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-gray-800">
                                 <i class="uil-edit-alt mr-1"></i>  Edit Post 
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-gray-800">
                                 <i class="uil-comment-slash mr-1"></i>   Disable comments
                                </a> 
                            </li> 
                            <li> 
                                <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-gray-800">
                                 <i class="uil-favorite mr-1"></i>  Add favorites 
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <hr class="-mx-2 my-2 dark:border-gray-800">
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-red-500 hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-red-500 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-red-600">
                                 <i class="uil-trash-alt mr-1"></i>  Delete
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                      
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="p-3 border-b dark:border-gray-700">
                    {{ post.description }}
                   </div>
                  <div uk-lightbox>
                      <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 p-2">
      
                          <a href="{{ post.pic_url }}" class="col-span-2">  
                              <img src="{{ post.pic_url }}" alt="" class="rounded-md w-full lg:h-76 object-cover">
                          </a>
                         
                         
                      </div>
                  </div>
      
                  <div class="p-4 space-y-3"> 
                     
                      <div class="flex space-x-4 lg:font-bold">
                          <a href="{% url 'feed:post-like' %}"  id="likebtn{{ post.id }}" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                              <div class="p-2 rounded-full  text-black lg:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-600">
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100">
                                      <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
                                  </svg>
                              </div>
                              <div> Like</div>
                          </a>
                          <a href="#" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                              <div class="p-2 rounded-full  text-black lg:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-600">
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100">
                                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 5v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-5l-5 4v-4H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V5a2 2 0 012-2h12a2 2 0 012 2zM7 8H5v2h2V8zm2 0h2v2H9V8zm6 0h-2v2h2V8z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                  </svg>
                              </div>
                              <div> Comment</div>
                          </a>
                          <a href="#" class="flex items-center space-x-2 flex-1 justify-end">
                              <div class="p-2 rounded-full  text-black lg:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-600">
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100">
                                      <path d="M15 8a3 3 0 10-2.977-2.63l-4.94 2.47a3 3 0 100 4.319l4.94 2.47a3 3 0 10.895-1.789l-4.94-2.47a3.027 3.027 0 000-.74l4.94-2.47C13.456 7.68 14.19 8 15 8z" />
                                  </svg>
                              </div>
                              <div> Share</div>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 pt-2"> 
                          <div class="flex items-center">
                              <img src="{{user.profile_pic.url}}" alt="" class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full border-2 border-white dark:border-gray-900">
            
                          </div>
                          <div class="dark:text-gray-100">
                              Liked <strong> Johnson</strong> and <strong> 12 Others </strong>
                          </div>
                      </div>
      
                      <div class="border-t py-4 space-y-4 dark:border-gray-600">
                          <div class="flex">
                              <div class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full relative flex-shrink-0">
                                  <img src="{{user.profile_pic.url}}" alt="" class="absolute h-full rounded-full w-full">
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                  <div class="text-gray-700 py-2 px-3 rounded-md bg-gray-100 relative lg:ml-5 ml-2 lg:mr-12 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100">
                                      {% for comment in posts.username.comments.all %}
                                      <p class="leading-6">{{ comment.body }} <urna class="i uil-heart"></urna>
                                         <i class="uil-grin-tongue-wink"> </i>
                                         </p>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                      <div class="absolute w-3 h-3 top-3 -left-1 bg-gray-100 transform rotate-45 dark:bg-gray-800"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="text-sm flex items-center space-x-3 mt-2 ml-5">
                                      <a href="#" class="text-red-600"> <i class="uil-heart"></i> Love </a>
                                      <a href="#"> Replay </a>
                                      <span> 3d </span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                         
                      </div>
                      
                      <a href="#" class="hover:text-blue-600 hover:underline">  Veiw 8 more Comments </a>
      
                      <div class="bg-gray-100 rounded-full relative dark:bg-gray-800 border-t">
                          <input placeholder="Add your Comment.." class="bg-transparent max-h-10 shadow-none px-5">
                          <div class="-m-0.5 absolute bottom-0 flex items-center right-3 text-xl">
                              <a href="#">
                                  <ion-icon name="happy-outline" class="hover:bg-gray-200 p-1.5 rounded-full"></ion-icon>
                              </a>
                              <a href="#">
                                  <ion-icon name="image-outline" class="hover:bg-gray-200 p-1.5 rounded-full"></ion-icon>
                              </a>
                              <a href="#">
                                  <ion-icon name="link-outline" class="hover:bg-gray-200 p-1.5 rounded-full"></ion-icon>
                              </a> 
                          </div>
                      </div>
      
                  </div>
      
              </div> 
              {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Share your comment model.

Comment: I just shared my model @WillemVanOnsem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the `Comment`s related to a `Post` with:

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {{ comment.body }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can efficiently fetch the related Comment's with one extra query (and not a query per `Post`), with:

```
context['posts'] = Post.objects.prefetch_related('comments')
```

Comment: Well i just did what your solution suggested but it return an empty object. comments doesn't show on the post related.

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma: then for that post there is no comment that links to the given post. `my_post` of course should be renamed to that variable you use for `Post` object that you are rendering.

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma: if you thus used `{% for post in posts %}...{% endfor %}`, then you use `{% for comment in post.comments.all %} ... {% endfor %}` (not `my_post`).

Comment: i did just that still getting empty related comment to the post! but if do something like this  ( post_comment = Comment.objects.filter()) then  context['post_comment'] = post_comment ,  i get all the comment but then it's not related to each post. So i am wondering where  this issue is coming from ?

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma: are you sure that the post that you show *has* **related** comments, so `Comment`s with `post` pointing to a `Post` that you render?

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma: it also does not make sense to pass the comments, so you can remove the `context['post_comment'] = ...` line...

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma: perhaps it is better to include the *full* template.

Comment: How do i  include the full template... ?  Yes i have add comment  to the post from the admin site. and i have taken the context[ 'post_comment' ]  =... line and  it's strange it's not working , this is making my head spin around,i don't even know what to think anymore. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68243193/edit) the quetion with the full template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234494/discussion-between-abubakari-umarblackrussain-uma-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score -1):

```
{% for comment in posts.comments.all %}

{{ comment.body }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.